# How to set a mime type on a file with php?

Tags: php, mime-types, fwrite

I am writing a Unit Test for a class and need to generate a few files with different mime-types.

I know how to set the mime-type when sending a file to a remote user (ala `header()`), but how to do it when using `fwrite()` on the local server?

For a file generated in this method is the mime-type derived directly from the file extension?

I'm using PHP 5.3.x on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Files don't have mime types. They are identified by their file extensions. The mime types are usually set by file extensions in `/etc/mime.types`. All the mime type does is tell the client what program to use to open the file.

Answer (score 3):

mime-type usually makes sense for web browsers and email clients only NOT for your physical files. Just create your files with correct extensions and Ubuntu File Manager will interpret it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The mime-type belongs to the HTTP request your server or browser does.
If you're running Apache, your can set default mime-types for your media files in .htaccess file. Then you can try to mock the request return your files with CURL or fsockopen and look in the header if the mime-type was correctly... just in case you want make sure in your unit test, that mime-types work correctly.